# Form action open in window.showModalDialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.open

I have here dynamic dropdownlist. When I select in dropdownlists the page goes to the action url, but what I need to do instead of going to action url, open it in window.showModalDialog. How to do that? Help?

```
<form action="url.php" method="post" id="myform">
<select name="drop_1" id="drop_1" onchange="showUser(this.value)" style="overflow:scroll;width:100px;text-transform:uppercase;">
        <option value="ALL" selected='ALL'>ALL</option>
        <?php getTierOne(); ?>
</select>

    <span id="wait_1" style="display: none;">
    <img alt="Please Wait" src="images/ajax-loader.gif" width="15px" height="15px"/>
    </span>
    <span id="result_1" style="display: none;"></span>
</form>

<script>function modalWin() {
if (window.showModalDialog) {
window.showModalDialog("url.php","name",
"dialogWidth:650px;dialogHeight:650px;");
} else {
window.open('url.php','name',
'height=255,width=250,toolbar=no,directories=no,status=no,menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no ,modal=yes');
}
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a ajax call to your action using jquery and return whatever data you need in your modal. Then on success add your data returned into the model(if necessary) and display the model.

Info can be found here -> https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/